# Paypal valid card types

Tags: paypal

I realize that this question is off-topic for this site but I followed a link to the Paypal developer forum on [this page](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/support) and it brought me here.

I just need a list of valid payment card types when adding a card to the vault as documented [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/store-a-credit-card/#store-a-credit-card)

I've not turned up anything with a Google search, if someone could provide a link to a resource I'd be grateful

Answer (score 2):

It seems that that if you send an invalid type the API will return an error message containing the valid types

```
 object(stdClass)#5 (5) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(16) "VALIDATION_ERROR"
  ["details"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#6 (2) {
      ["field"]=>
      string(4) "type"
      ["issue"]=>
      string(71) "Value is invalid (must be visa, mastercard, amex, discover, or maestro)"
    }
 }
  ["message"]=>
  string(29) "Invalid request - see details"
  ["information_link"]=>
  string(55) "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#VALIDATION_ERROR"
  ["debug_id"]=>
  string(13) "1c7015dd4cdfc"
}
```